# Sharing test code between Intellij maven modules

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven, intellij-idea

I'm having some trouble sharing test code in Intellij.
I have a module called Shared and another called Server so following this guide (http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-attached-tests.html) I managed to export a test jar from the shared module.

The problem is that I'm already using the shared module as a dependency in server. Now I want to use its test code as well and I can't do it because the existing dependency ignores the test code.

Is there any way to achieve this without creating a new module just for the test code?

Comment: You can create a test-artifact containing your test code which you can then use elsewhere.  Only use this facility sparingly - in my experience it does not scale well.

Comment: "I'm already using the shared module as a dependency in server". Yes you need to use it... what is wrong in adding test jar with defined scope -- test ?

Comment: You depend on the shared jar in the server with a compile scope, and depend on the test-jar in the server with a test scope.

Comment: I think I'm doing exactly that, having two dependencies for the shared module. One of them is using the test jar with a test scope and the other is using the main source with a compile scope. Still I cant access the objects included in the shared tests.